# CSS3 Draw border animation

Tags: css, animation, border

I'm trying to animate a border in css3 to have a drawing effect (loops round from right to left)

At the moment I just have it so it fades in on hover

```
.info-circle-sub-def{
border: 1px solid #111111;
border-radius: 50%;
}

.info-circle-sub-def:hover{
animation: drawBorder 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes drawBorder {
to {
border: 1px solid #d6a318;
}
}
```

[image of golden border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjL5b.png)

Comment: https://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/ may help you.

Comment: Check this demo https://codepen.io/giana/pen/yYBpVY/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this quick pen I just made. You can edit for your needs.

`pen example`https://codepen.io/stojko/pen/YZgByQ